# Whitespace around ggplot/Sweave generated plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, sweave

I am creating mapplots in using this code:

```
ggplot(fl, aes(long, lat, group = group)) +
    geom_polygon(aes(fill = density)) + guides(fill=FALSE) +
    geom_path(colour = "white", size = .1, alpha = .5) +
    scale_x_continuous(name = "", labels = NULL, breaks = NULL) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "", labels = NULL, breaks = NULL) +
    coord_fixed()
```

Lat, long, and group are what you'd expect and this produces a map of Florida with counties different shades of blue.  When I do this, it generates a PDF that is 6-in square.  But the underlying plot is not square and for Maryland, it is really 5x3 or so.  How can I force ggplot to create a PDF without excess whitespace surrounding the plot for better inclusion through Sweave?

Comment: set the width and height of the device / chunk to 5x3.

Comment: Is there a way to determine the correct width/height programatically?

Comment: [not really](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16422847/471093)

Comment: Surely there's a better way of dealing with this, right?

Comment: @JamesHoward There is, but it's a white wizard level secret. Sorry.

Comment: I think this question just became an RPG.

Comment: I think it should be closed as a duplicate

Comment: Probably for the best.