# How to retrieve ggplot2 inner plot size and margins length

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I am working on custom ggplot2 items and want to compute the size of the actual plot without the margins.

Suppose this plot

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = cyl, y = hp )) + geom_point() + ggtitle('test') + theme_bw()
```

I need to retrive the length (relative or absolute) of the margins (see red lines) or somehow the size of the plot and its relative position to the top left corner.

[image]

Is there any way to retrieve this info from the ggplot2 object?

Comment: *very* related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60803424/npc-coordinates-of-geom-point-in-ggplot2

Comment: This is still relying on internal margins only

Comment: [and also very related.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16442029/7941188) Note Baptiste's comment *the plot panel size will be 0 by default, as it is meant to be calculated on-the-fly according to the device (viewport) it lives in, not the opposite.*

Comment: *This is still relying on internal margins only* - What do you mean? The linked post does pretty much show what you are asking for? If not, please kindly clarify how your question is different. Cheers

Comment: I need the size of the inner plot.
As in, image the plot is 400x300, I need to know what are the margins and what is the size of the inner plot (inside the box, suppose 380x250)